# Xamarin.Forms - possible to set an element property globally?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, monkeypatching

Say I want an Entry element to not have auto-correct or auto-capitalize. This can be done by setting its Keyboard property like so:

```
new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(0) }
```

Now, how do I make that the **global default for all Entry elements**?

I know I can create a **custom** element that inherits from the built-in element, and override the property that way, like:

```
public class EntryCustom : Entry
{
    public EntryCustom()
    {
        Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(0);
    }
}
```

and then simply call it like:

```
new EntryCustom { ... }
```

But is there a way to do this directly on the built-in element type, without creating a custom element type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by saving the custom keyboard into a static and then binding it to all Entry fields using a default style. You can place that default style into an application-wide resource dictionary, which is automatically applied throughout the application. Here is sample code that I just tested to verify in a new empty Forms project:

**Step 1. Save the custom keyboard into a static.**

Keyboards.cs (static custom keyboard):

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace KeyboardDemo
{
    public static class Keyboards
    {
        public static Keyboard Unassisted { get; private set; }

        static Keyboards ()
        {
            Unassisted = Keyboard.Create (0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2. Create an App.xaml for your project.**

Follow this tip to add an App.xaml to your Forms project: http://jfarrell.net/2015/02/02/centralize-your-styles-with-xamarin-forms/

**Step 3. Add the default style to App.xaml**

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:demo="clr-namespace:KeyboardDemo" 
        x:Class="KeyboardDemo.App">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="EntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="{x:Static demo:Keyboards.Unassisted}" />
            </Style>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" TargetType="Entry" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

**Step 4. Add a new page to the project**

Add a ContentPage to the application, with plain Entry controls to verify the styling.

App.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace KeyboardDemo
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            MainPage = new MyPage ();
        }
    }
}
```

MyPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="KeyboardDemo.MyPage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,20,0,0" Android="0" WinPhone="0" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Coming back to this answer after gaining some new found XAML knowledge and figuring out how to do this all from XAML!

See below for adding the `Keyboard` with `KeyboardFlag`s to a `Style` using only XAML.

Also see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/#Specifying_additional_keyboard_options) for available `KeyboardFlag` values. I am just using `None` below.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Keyboard x:Key="NoCapitalizationKeyboard"
              x:FactoryMethod="Create">
      <x:Arguments>
        <KeyboardFlags>None</KeyboardFlags>
      </x:Arguments>
    </Keyboard>

    <Style x:Key="NoCapitalizationEntryStyle"
           TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="Keyboard"
                    Value="{StaticResource NoCapitalizationKeyboard}">
        </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource NoCapitalizationEntryStyle}"
           TargetType="Entry" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Entry />
```

-- Old Answer --

Unfortunately I do not think you can do that with Global Styles, since you can only set the Keyboard to one of the predefined keyboard sets listed [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/) as opposed to being able to individually turn specific functionality on and off.

Another option would be to create a custom renderer for the Entry control itself and then implement code to turn it off in each platform. Something like [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/133087/#Comment_133087) for iOS (except I think you would use `Control.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None;`).

Comment: The `Keyboard` property is bindable, so it can indeed be assigned via a Style.

Comment: @KiethRome Right, but that forces you to choose the preselected keyboards Xamarin has available. You can not only disable auto-capitalization using styles. So you could choose Text or Number or what ever but that also changes other keyboard properties and not just auto-capitalization. *Edit: Seeing you answer now! I take it all back ;)